# Reference variable form name in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several forms generated within a ng-repeat:

```
<div class="familyMembers" data-ng-repeat="member in familyMembers">
    ...
    <form class="familyMemberEdit" name="familyMemberEdit_{{ member.spid }}" novalidate>
    ...
    </form>
    ...
</div>
```

In the corresponding controller I want to check for $dirty on each of these forms:

```
...
var a = '';
var condition = false;
angular.forEach($scope.familyMembers, function(value, key) {
    a = 'familyMemberEdit_' + value.spid;
    condition = condition || $scope[a].$dirty;
});
return condition;
```

Referring to `$scope[a]` returns `undefined`. How should I reference `$scope.familyMemberEdit_1234` in this case?

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates a new scope and hence, the forms are not available on the parent scope.

Comment: Ok, is there any other way to check if those forms were changed (I only want to show the Save button when there are changes to be saved)

Comment: will be nice if you post some Fiddle/Plunker

Comment: A friend suggested the following solution that works:

On the form I added an `id`: `id="familyMemberEdit_{{member.spid}}"`.

The method that checks each form now looks like:

    `var formElement;
    angular.forEach($scope.familyMembers, function(value, key) {
        formElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('familyMemberEdit_' + value.spid)).scope();
        if (formElement && formElement["familyMemberEdit_{{member.spid}}"]) {
            condition = condition || formElement["familyMemberEdit_{{member.spid}}"].$dirty;
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I can give a workaround which i have not tested. You need to push the forms that are created into an array on the parent scope. `ng-init` on the form html can be used i think

```
 <form class="familyMemberEdit" name="familyMemberEdit_{{ member.spid }}" novalidate ng-init="addForm(this['familyMemberEdit_'+member.spid])">
```

On the controller

```
$scope.addForm=function(form) {
    forms.add(form);
}
.
```